# Coldfusion 7 - mail sending bad 'helo'

Tags: email, coldfusion, cfmail, coldfusion-7

I've got my own box sitting in a rack. It's Win2000 running CF 7 and using the rack company's smtp server. I can't send emails. When I try, they simply go to the undeliverable email folder. Support says my server is sending a non-verifiable `helo` message. So their smtp server wont send it.

It being CF 7, the admin has nowhere to specify U/P for auth. However I SHOULD be able to do that within the tag. When I do, I get no errors but the mail goes to the undeliverable folder.

**CODE:**

```
<cftry>
    <cfmail to="jxxx@yahoo.com" 
            from="jxxx@xxx.com" 
            subject="xxx.com Sign-up" 
            server="smtp.xxx.net" 
            port="25" 
            username="valid-account@xxx.net" 
            password="password" >

            This is a test - with server specified
    </cfmail>
    Success w/ server user defined

    <cfcatch type="any">
            <strong>ERROR: #cfcatch.Message#</strong><BR />
            #cfcatch.Detail#
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>        


<cftry>
    <cfmail to="jxxx@yahoo.com" 
            from="xxx@xxx.net" 
            subject="xxx.com Sign-up" >

            This is a test - without server specified
    </cfmail>
    Success w/o server user defined

    <cfcatch type="any">
            <strong>ERROR: #cfcatch.Message#</strong><BR />
            #cfcatch.Detail#
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

I don't know much about mail servers...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with DNS and the inability of the receiving system to either do a reverse DNS lookup or maybe it isn't in DNS at all.

another possibility is that non-verifable Helo means that you don't have FQDN associated with the system (perhaps your system name does not have a domain associated with it?) (ie. helo me) probably going to be bounced versus "helo me.somewhere.com".

so - don't think this a CF issue from a coding perspective - something that is related to your system setting (FQDN perhaps) or DNS in your location.  Most anti-spam / anti-open relay settings are going to look at DNS for some level of validation.

Comment: are you saying the system (machine name) - totally unconnected to a site or code - will have an effect on mail request to a mail server?

So if my server is named "qwe234" as opposed to "myDomain.com" - it could have an effect?